# Access 2003 VBA Get Active filter?

Tags: ms-access, vba

is there a way to retrieve the active filter on a form via VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the contents of the filter property (immediate window):

```
?Screen.ActiveForm.Filter
(([FormName].FieldName="a"))
```

Other possibilities:

```
sFilter=Me.Filter

sFilter=Forms!FormName.Filter
```

Comment: You might want to check if .FilterOn is true or false, as a form can have a .Filter property assigned while .FilterOn is false, which means the form will not actually be filtered.