# Set a fields default value in form the same as filter

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I open a form with a filter. When i create a new record using this form i want a field to get the same default value as the filter. (So that the new record will be a part of the current filter result).
When i open the form i save the filter value in a tempvar.

How can i achieve this in a simple way?

I have tried the the two latter ways to get the current filter from this question: [Access 2003 VBA Get Active filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382739/access-2003-vba-get-active-filter)

I did not understand the former.

I have not programmed Visual Basic before, nor have i used Access to any significant degree. So i might need a pretty detailed explanation.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Currently i open the form by clicking on one of the fields in another table using a macro. the macro opens a form relating to another table filtering it by the value in the field i just pressed. The value i of the the field i pressed is stored in an [tempvar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb257080%28v=office.12%29.aspx) object. I hope this was clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Access don't have that functionality. And you have to learn VBA to implement this.

I think it will be difficult to analyze the filter. On my opinion it would be easier to set filter and defaul value for each field. There is need implement function for opening a form and some public form methods to set values.

The function for opening form can look like:

```
Dim frm as Form_SomeForm

DoCmd.OpenForm "SomeForm", , , , , acHiden

Set frm = Forms("SomeForm")

frm.SetControlFilter("UserName", "=", "Foo")
frm.SetControlFilter("Age", "=", "123")
...

frm.ApplyFilter()

frm.Visible = True
```

The form module "SomeForm" can look like:

```
Dim m_stFiler as String

Public Sub SetControlFilter(ByVal stCtrl As String, ByVal stExp As String, ByVal stValue as String) 
    Dim ctl As Control

    '-- set default value
    set ctl = Me("stCtrl")

    ctl.DefaultValue = "=""" & stValue  & """"

    '-- build filter
    If m_stFiler <> "" Then m_stFiler = m_stFiler & " AND "
    m_stFiler = m_stFiler & ctl.ControlSource & " " & stExp & " "" & stValue & "" "

End Sub

Public Sub ApplyFilter()
    Me.Filter = m_stFiler
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As i have never programmed VBA i am not fully able to comprehend what your code does. However if this works, there is one more thing i need implemented: I want the filter that is applied to be dynamic in the sense that it corresponds to the value of the field i click in the first form.

Comment: Quick question: Should the second Codeblock be pasted into the form_Someform class, in a newly created SomeForm Module or a new SomeForm class Module?

Comment: Ooops, I made a mistake: m_stFiler = ctl.ControlSource.
Should be m_stFiler = m_stFiler & ctl.ControlSource...

Comment: Second codeblock should be part of Form_SomeForm class. It's generating by Access when you create a form.

Answer (score 0):

Sergeys Answer put me on the right track.

I had to do some tweeks.

it only worked for one Field and i had to call the methodsas this:

```
Call frm.SetControlFilter("Age", "=", "123")
```

For some reason i also had to save the stCtrl in a new internal variable as this:

```
Dim stCon As String
stCon = stCtrl
'-- set default value
Set ctl = Me(stCon)
```

Thanks A Lot

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this question is about opening a record from a form to view a child form with the selected master record filtered. So that when you then add more records to the child form, you are inheriting the master record ID into each child.

If that is the case, there is an easier way to do it:

1) create a child form "MyChildForm" where the row source is the same as the master form, this is like a sort of dummy from, used to house the master ID.

2) within "MyChildForm", create a sub form with the child data you want to edit

3) link "MyChildForm" form with it's subform using the link master/child fields property, found by selecting the bounding box of the sub form, then properties, then Data tab.

4) create a button on your master form to open the child form

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyChildForm", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & Me.ID
```

And that's it...

Apologies if that wasn't what you were looking for, and you actually wanted to pass filters for some other reason.